# How does a samba/cifs recycle bin work within PCmanFM?

Tags: lubuntu, samba, cifs, trash, pcmanfm

By using `vfs object = recycle` I can create a trash bin for a samba share (or more globally, for each samba share).

However, when using PCmanFM as file manager in Lubuntu 18.04 this seems not to work: When trying to delete a file PCmanFM pops up a message that says that there is no recycle bin, none can be created and therefore the files cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this is a permission problem. But then I realised that I had to tic `Delete files from removable disks instead of moving them to trash` in the settings of PCmanFM.

This way the files can be deleted and then are **moved to the recycle bin of the samba server**.